# Nas with raspberry pi - how to connect through windows

Tags: nas, raspberry-pi

I have setup a raspberry pi nas and it works nice but I want to share the HDD which is connect via usb to the raspberry pi and not the sd card which is on the raspberry pi. How can I make it ?

I have mount my HDD with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/shares/public/disk1`

When I tried to add with `\\raspberrypi\public\disk1` Windows say that he need a username and a password. When I have setup my nas with samba, I have do this : `sudo smbpasswd -a pi` and I have give the same password that is use for my session. But when i'm on Windows, he tell me that the password is incorect, what should I do ?

Comment: There are tons of guides out there that describe this in detail.

Comment: Thanx for helping me. If you can explain me a solution that would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but it sounds like you added pi as a samba user without setting pi up as a samba user.

What you should have done:

- Add in a user that can access the Pi’s samba shares. Make an account with the username **username** and the password **password**. You can make your username and password whatever you wish. To do so type the following commands:

  sudo useradd username -m -G users

  sudo passwd username
- You’ll be prompted to type in the password twice to confirm. After confirming the password, it’s time to add “username” as a legitimate Samba user. Enter the following command (this is what I think you did):

  sudo smbpasswd -a username
- Enter the password for the account when prompted.

You can now hop onto any Samba-capable machine on your network and test connectivity to the network share.

And here's where I found that info, its the guide I use: [Rasp Pi NAS](https://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/)

Comment: When I type sudo smbpasswd -a backups it ask me twice for SMB password but after that, it return me "Failed to add entry for user backups."

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had a typo. Should have said sudo smbpasswd -a username. I was editing this another source to be more generic and suitable to the scenario.

Comment: Because you are now adding the user as a samba user. Previous step creates the user.

Comment: Okey but now Windows say me "access denied", username and password are correct but acces is denied. I'm almost sure that it's a problem from the smb.conf file

Comment: What's you config file look like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yNgVnDD0

Comment: Are your permissions correct? What does fstab show? Can you connect to the pi itself (the SD card root)? Or are you denied from the whole thing?